# Using lapply to match list elements and dataframe values (lookup-table)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, match, lapply

I would like to match Elements of a `list` with elements of a `data.frame`. The result should be again a `list`.

So, here is a `data.frame`

```
data.f <- data.frame(seq(1:3), c("1", "1,3", "2,3,4"))
names(data.f) <- c("unit", "description")
> data.f
  unit description
1    1           1
2    2         1,3
3    3       2,3,4
```

And here is the list

```
list.1 <- list(c(1), c(2,3), c(2), c(1,3))
> list.1
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
[1] 1 3
```

The common element of list and data.frame is the "unit" (1, 2, 3). I need a new list, which contains the "description" instead of the unit. Again, more then one argument may be passed to each list element.

The result should look like this list:

```
list.result <- list(c("1"), c("1,3", "2,3,4"), c("1,3"), c("1", "2,3,4"))
> list.result
[[1]]
[1] "1"

[[2]]
[1] "1,3"   "2,3,4"

[[3]]
[1] "1,3"

[[4]]
[1] "1"     "2,3,4"
```

I'd think `lapply`is the function of choice here? Though I am not sure how to match the `list`and the `data.frame` in the lapply argument/function. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` to extract the 'description' column based on the index from 'list.1'

```
Map(`[`,list(as.character(data.f$description)), list.1)
#[[1]]
#[1] "1"

#[[2]]
#[1] "1,3"   "2,3,4"

#[[3]]
#[1] "1,3"

#[[4]]
#[1] "1"     "2,3,4"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` for every element in list and then `match` them with `unit` in dataframe and get the corresponding `description` value.

```
lapply(list.1, function(x) as.character(data.f$description[match(x, data.f$unit)]))

#[[1]]
#[1] "1"

#[[2]]
#[1] "1,3"   "2,3,4"

#[[3]]
#[1] "1,3"

#[[4]]
#[1] "1"     "2,3,4"
```